# Overlay image failing to load on GoogleMaps - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, user-interface, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm facing an issue when using an image as a ground overlay. The first few times with a fresh install the image loads fine and after it doesn't display at all. For some context: I have a list of images and when tapping on one it displays the image and markers on top of the map. The second time I do it the image fails to load.It seems to be a memory/caching issue but haven't been able to find a solution.

Currently using GoogleMaps SDK Version 8.1.0

Any idea what could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same using 8.0.0 on iOS via Cocoapods.
After some digging, I found that despite the image supplied is valid and the GMSGroundOverlay is properly added to the map, it occasionally disappears during runtime.

it turns out that when we used an earlier version (4.1.0), this wasn't happening. I tested my way up to at least 5.1.0 where this issue wasn't happening any more for me. If this is the issue you're having... not really offering a cause, but a solution at least.

Comment: Hey, so yeah this is pretty much what I did. Except I kept downgrading from 8.0.1 to 7.0.0 and that started working... at least with larger images with 500~ kBs or higher which I think is fine for me.

In 5.1.0 do all image overlays work? I hope GoogleMaps fixes this as I don't think MapKit supports overlay images.

Comment: Haven't tried larger-scale images; all around 100-300 KB so far. I'm also stuck with Cocoapods for now; once SPM support is readily available for GMaps iOS, I'll revisit the issue.